# Hide tmux pane border

Tags: linux, tmux, i3-window-manager

This is currently what my tmux pane borders look like:
[image]

This is multiple terminals open in i3 (what I would like to have it look like in tmux):
[image]

Is it possible to just make the pane borders invisible? I tried setting `set -g pane-border-status off` in tmux.conf, but that did not make any difference.

Comment: Perhaps you could set the border color to match your background? https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/141252/2298

Comment: I thought about that, but I was hoping there was a way to make the borders truly invisible.

Answer (score 0):

```
set-window-option -g pane-border-status off
```

Now works as expected. One benefit: when I set both,

```
set-option -g status off
```

If I do not turn off the border and place it at the bottom of the pane, the command prompt mode will not work properly.
Those who share my confusion may find a way around the conflict here. Possible conflicts between the status bar, border, and command prompt mode have been avoided for the time being.